# Is there is any library to convert wikitext to html format using php?

Tags: php, mediawiki, wiki-engine

How can i convert the wikitext to html format using php ? If anyone knows the libraries please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Stop putting `[meta]` as the only tag on your questions. It's not useful.

Answer (score 7):

MediaWiki.org has a list of [alternative parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers). A few of them use PHP.

As cbuckley indicated, [MediaWiki's own parser](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParser.php) is also written in php, but it is surely too tightly woven into MediaWiki to be of use to you.

You can also run your wikitext through the [MediaWiki API's parse function](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParse) or if you are exporting content from a running MediaWiki installation, fetch parsed content from the API directly: see [this example on the Stack Overflow article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Stack%20Overflow).

Finally, you can get the non-API part of MediaWiki to output raw article HTML using "action=render". [See this example on the Stack Overflow article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stack_overflow&action=render).

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about MediaWiki, the [manual page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParser.php) for their parser may help you; there is a link to their source from there. It's not insubstantial, but you might be able to pull from it the bits relevant to you.